# How is the "base value" of SHAP values calculated?

Tags: lightgbm, explainable-ai, shap

I'm trying to understand how the base value is calculated. So I used an example from SHAP's github notebook, [Census income classification with LightGBM](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/tree_explainer/Census%20income%20classification%20with%20LightGBM.ipynb).

Right after I trained the lightgbm model, I applied `explainer.shap_values()` on each row of the test set individually. By using `force_plot()`, it yields the base value, model output value, and the contributions of features, as shown below:
[image]

My understanding is that the base value is derived when the model has no features. But how is it actually calculated in SHAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, it's the value of a feature-less model, which generally is the average of the outcome variable in the training set (often in log-odds, if classification).  With `force_plot`, you actually pass your desired base value as the first parameter; in that notebook's case it is `explainer.expected_value[1]`, the average of the second class.

https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/06c9d18f3dd014e9ed037a084f48bfaf1bc8f75a/shap/plots/force.py#L31

https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/352#issuecomment-447485624

Comment: I don't really get the sense of a feature-less model. I know this is the correct explanation given also by the author of the original paper, but I am not able to understand it. Wouldn't that prediction obtained by my trained model that actually use some features?

Comment: @Alexbrini, according to my understanding the featureless model can simply predict a fixed value (eg the average of the output), with no features used whatsoever.

Comment: Do you know what does it mean when I see `0.5` as base value for all my instances? when I plot waterfall plot, I see `0` for all my instances. You can refer this post here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569843/why-shap-base-value-is-0-5-for-all-my-instances-and-what-does-it-mean